# Function forget() return Call to undefined method in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I try to use the `forget()` method to removes an item from the collection I have error:

> Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyThrough::forget()

My Model `City.php`

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class City extends Model
{
    public function rooms(){
      return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Room','App\Object');
    }
}
```

My method which contains `forget()`

```
public function getSearchResults($request){
    $request->flash();
    if($request->input('city')!=null){
      $result = $this->fR->getSearchResults($request->input('city'));
      if($result){

        foreach($result->rooms as $k=>$room)
        {
          if($request->input('room_size') > 0)
          {
            if($request->input('room_size') != $room->room_size)
            {
              $result->rooms()->forget($k);
            }
          }
        }

        return $result;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

What can I do to fix it?
Thanks for help

Comment: Forget usually refers to the cache. Did you mean something like `detatch` ?

Comment: I wanted to exclude elements that not match the search results... forget is not good in this case?

Comment: `$result->rooms()` looks like a relationship query. It wouldn't have forget. Maybe  `$result->rooms->forget($k)` might work since that would be the result collection.

Comment: I think you're right. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your code below way and after clear the cache.

```
public function getSearchResults($request){
    $request->flash();
    if($request->input('city')!=null){
      $result = $this->fR->getSearchResults($request->input('city'));
      if($result){

        foreach($result->rooms as $k=>$room)
        {
          if($request->input('room_size') > 0)
          {
            if($request->input('room_size') != $room->room_size)
            {
              $result->rooms->forget($k);
            }
          }
        }

        return $result;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

and then run below command

```
php artisan cache:clear
Artisan::call('cache:clear');
```